# Orchard CMS Driver's Editor Override Not Firing

Tags: content-management-system, orchardcms

**Using Orchard 1.7.**

**The goal:** is to create a collection of what we're calling page filters.

To create the many to many part I followed the tutorial steps described [Here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Creating-1-n-and-n-n-relations)

**The problem:** My Editor override in my driver class is never hit and an empty create page with nothing but a save button is being returned.

Model classes:

```
namespace MyLib.Orchard.HyperlinkItemManager.Models
{
    public class HyperlinkPageFilterRecord
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int PageId { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MyLib.Orchard.HyperlinkItemManager.Models
{
    public class HyperlinkPageFiltersContentRecord
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual HyperlinkPageFiltersPartRecord HyperlinkPageFiltersPartRecord { get; set; }
        public virtual HyperlinkPageFilterRecord HyperlinkPageFilterRecord { get; set; }
    }

}
namespace MyLib.Orchard.HyperlinkItemManager.Models
{
    public class HyperlinkPageFiltersPart : ContentPart<HyperlinkPageFiltersPartRecord>
    {
        public IEnumerable<HyperlinkPageFilterRecord> HyperlinkPageFilters
        {
            get
            {
                return Record.HyperlinkPageFilters.Select(r => r.HyperlinkPageFilterRecord);
            }
        }
    }
}


namespace MyLib.Orchard.HyperlinkItemManager.Models
{
    public class HyperlinkPageFiltersPartRecord : ContentPartRecord
    {
        public virtual IList<HyperlinkPageFiltersContentRecord> HyperlinkPageFilters { get; set; }
        public HyperlinkPageFiltersPartRecord()
        {
            HyperlinkPageFilters = new List<HyperlinkPageFiltersContentRecord>();
        }
    }
}
```

View model class:

```
namespace MyLib.Orchard.HyperlinkItemManager.Models
{
    public class HyperlinkPageFiltersEditViewModel
    {
        public IList<HyperlinkPageFilterEntry> HyperlinkPageFilters { get; set; }
    }

    public class HyperlinkPageFilterEntry
    {
        public HyperlinkPageFilterRecord HyperlinkPageFilter { get; set; }
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Services:

```
   namespace MyLib.Orchard.HyperlinkItemManager.Services
    {
        public interface IHyperlinkPageFiltersService : IDependency
        {
            void UpdateHyperlinkPageFiltersForContentItem(
                ContentItem item,
                IEnumerable<HyperlinkPageFilterEntry> HyperlinkPageFilters);
            IEnumerable<HyperlinkPageFilterRecord> GetHyperlinkPageFilters();
        }

        public class HyperlinkPageFiltersService : IHyperlinkPageFiltersService
        {
            private readonly IRepository<HyperlinkPageFilterRecord>
                _HyperlinkPageFilterRepository;
            private readonly IRepository<HyperlinkPageFiltersContentRecord>
                _contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRepository;

            public HyperlinkPageFiltersService(
                IRepository<HyperlinkPageFilterRecord> HyperlinkPageFilterRepository,
                IRepository<HyperlinkPageFiltersContentRecord> contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRepository)
            {

                _HyperlinkPageFilterRepository = HyperlinkPageFilterRepository;
                _contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRepository = contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRepository;
            }

            public void UpdateHyperlinkPageFiltersForContentItem(
                ContentItem item,
                IEnumerable<HyperlinkPageFilterEntry> HyperlinkPageFilters)
            {

                var record = item.As<HyperlinkPageFiltersPart>().Record;
                var oldHyperlinkPageFilters = _contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRepository.Fetch(
                    r => r.HyperlinkPageFiltersPartRecord == record);
                var lookupNew = HyperlinkPageFilters
                    .Where(e => e.IsChecked)
                    .Select(e => e.HyperlinkPageFilter)
                    .ToDictionary(r => r, r => false);
                // Delete the rewards that are no longer there
                // and mark the ones that should stay
                foreach (var contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRecord in oldHyperlinkPageFilters)
                {
                    if (lookupNew.ContainsKey(
                        contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRecord.HyperlinkPageFilterRecord))
                    {

                        lookupNew[contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRecord.HyperlinkPageFilterRecord]
                            = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRepository.Delete(contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRecord);
                    }
                }
                // Add the new rewards
                foreach (var HyperlinkPageFilter in lookupNew.Where(kvp => !kvp.Value)
                                               .Select(kvp => kvp.Key))
                {
                    _contentHyperlinkPageFiltersRepository.Create(new HyperlinkPageFiltersContentRecord
                    {
                        HyperlinkPageFiltersPartRecord = record,
                        HyperlinkPageFilterRecord = HyperlinkPageFilter
                    });
                }
            }

            public IEnumerable<HyperlinkPageFilterRecord> GetHyperlinkPageFilters()
            {
                return _HyperlinkPageFilterRepository.Table.ToList();
            }
```

Migration:

```
    public int UpdateFrom11()
    {
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("HyperlinkPageFiltersPartRecord",
        table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
        );

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("HyperlinkPageFilterRecord",
        table => table
            .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
            .Column<int>("PageId")
        );

        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("HyperlinkPageFiltersContentRecord",
            table => table
                .Column<int>("Id", column => column.PrimaryKey().Identity())
                .Column<int>("HyperlinkPageFiltersPartRecord_Id")
                .Column<int>("HyperlinkPageFilterRecord_Id")
            );
        return 12;
    }



    public int UpdateFrom12() {
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterTypeDefinition("HyperlinkPageFiltersPart", builder => builder
            .DisplayedAs("Hyperlink Page Filters")
            .WithPart("HyperlinkPageFiltersPart")
            );
        return 13;
    }
    public int UpdateFrom13()
    {
        ContentDefinitionManager.AlterPartDefinition(
            "HyperlinkPageFiltersPart",
            builder => builder.Attachable());
        return 14;
    }
    }
}
```

and lastly... the driver that we don't hit...

```
namespace MyLib.Orchard.HyperlinkItemManager.Drivers
{
    [UsedImplicitly]
    public class HyperlinkPageFiltersPartDriver : ContentPartDriver<HyperlinkPageFiltersPart>
    {
        private readonly IHyperlinkPageFiltersService _hyperlinkPageFiltersService;
        private IContentManager _contentManager;

        //private const string TemplateName = "Parts/HyperlinkPageFilters";

        public HyperlinkPageFiltersPartDriver(IHyperlinkPageFiltersService hyperlinkPageFiltersService, IContentManager contentManager)
        {
            _hyperlinkPageFiltersService = hyperlinkPageFiltersService;
            _contentManager = contentManager;
        }

        protected override string Prefix
        {
            get { return "HyperlinkPageFilters"; }
        }

        protected override DriverResult Display(HyperlinkPageFiltersPart part,string displayType,dynamic shapeHelper)
        {

            return ContentShape("Parts_HyperlinkPageFilters", () => shapeHelper.Parts_HyperlinkPageFilters(
                                ContentPart: part,
                                HyperlinkPageFilters: part.HyperlinkPageFilters));
        }

        protected override DriverResult Editor(HyperlinkPageFiltersPart part, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {


            return ContentShape("Parts_HyperlinkPageFilters_Edit",
                    () => shapeHelper.EditorTemplate(
                        TemplateName: "Parts.HyperlinkPageFilters.Edit",
                        Model: BuildEditorViewModel(part),
                        Prefix: Prefix));
        }

        protected override DriverResult Editor(HyperlinkPageFiltersPart part, IUpdateModel updater, dynamic shapeHelper)
        {

            var model = new HyperlinkPageFiltersEditViewModel();
            updater.TryUpdateModel(model, Prefix, null, null);

            if (part.ContentItem.Id != 0)
            {
                _hyperlinkPageFiltersService.UpdateHyperlinkPageFiltersForContentItem(
                    part.ContentItem, model.HyperlinkPageFilters);
            }

            return Editor(part, shapeHelper);
        }

        private HyperlinkPageFiltersEditViewModel BuildEditorViewModel(HyperlinkPageFiltersPart part)
        {

            //get all pages
            var pages = _contentManager.Query("Pages");

            //get pagesfilters

            //check pages

            var itemRewards = part.HyperlinkPageFilters.ToLookup(r => r.Id);
            return new HyperlinkPageFiltersEditViewModel
            {
                HyperlinkPageFilters = _hyperlinkPageFiltersService.GetHyperlinkPageFilters().Select(
                    r => new HyperlinkPageFilterEntry
                    {
                        HyperlinkPageFilter = r,
                        IsChecked = itemRewards.Contains(r.Id)
                    }).ToList()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
namespace MyLib.Orchard.HyperlinkItemManager.Handlers {
    public class HyperlinkPageFiltersPartHandler : ContentHandler {
        public HyperlinkPageFiltersPartHandler(IRepository<HyperlinkPageFiltersPartRecord> repository) {
            Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the override in your theme?

Comment: The override is in my module.

Comment: The only piece of code you're not showing seems to be the driver...

Comment: Did you activate the module? I know is a silly question but sometimes...

Comment: Do you have a handler for each of those parts?

Comment: Yes the module is activated.
The only handler i have is the one described in the tutorial, now displayed above.

Comment: Have you added Parts_HyperlinkPageFilters_Edit to your Placement.info?